# How would I display a random row from my MySQL database every 30 days?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am working on my members system and I want to display a "Featured Member" in the sidebar every 30 days, I want the selection to be random. Any ideas? Tips?

EDIT: I understand how to query the database to display a random row, I was wondering what I would have to do to **display the data every 30 days**

Comment: Please do a search. There are ***many*** topics on this.

Comment: If you want to display the same member for 30 days you have to save that information somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually 2 questions:

~ get a random member

~ display a member for 30 days

The first part can be done using the SQL query from JW or by a range of other query methods.

The second part has to be done using PHP. There are a number of ways to do this and the most interesting part of your problem to me is changing it *every 30 days*.

Personally I'd either a cron job or use one a solutions based around whatever month it is and storing the random member with reference to that month stamp. If the month stamp changed the random member stored changes. Something like that.

Answer (score 2):

1. create a db table to store the current, and possibly the past picks
2. create a cron job that runs every 30 days
3. populate the table, taking in to consideration who was picked in the past
4. profit ! :-)

--use the table to select and show as appropriate.

Comment: +1 for the approach, which is about as much as this question should get. The advantage of this is it also allows "selective targeting" of the featured member, by leaving open "populate the [features user] table" as well as providing a means for historic data. Selecting random records is already covered by other SO questions.

Comment: I probably should have been more descriptive with my question but the main aspect of the question wasn't how to query the database to display random records, seeing as I have made the user registration/login portions of the script it is safe for me (if I was sitting from the other seat) to safely assume I understand how to query a database. The aim was towards displaying the data every 30 days.

Comment: @CoryAllen you can still edit your question. but since you have already chosen an answer i assume you don't need any more help

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM Members ORDER BY Rand() LIMIT 1`

That is all. You could do a cron job to run this query every 30 days.